# Can we transfer android data to desktop app via simple USB cable?

Tags: java, android, usb, communication, usbserial

I currently create an app for android; user take photo and add information (GPS localisation, text, etc...) on it.

There is also a java desktop app, who will contain data take with the android app and lot of other things.

So I need to transfer data from android tablet device Nexus 9 (5.0 and higher) to PC desktop app via USB simple cable, and without internet connection/WiFi/Bluetooth.

I have a button in desktop app who get data from the device and store it in a folder.

I found lot of things to make it with Bluetooth, web service and socket to transfer data, but without internet connection and only with USB cable restrein my possibility.

So before I start I'd like to know if such thing is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need to pass by the java desktop app. Morever i read transfer file via android app to computer it's not possible.

Comment: @ Arun Chand I totally disagree. When an Android is connected to a PC you can never use the USB Host mode because the PC can not act as USB slave. The only chance I see is enabling development mode on the Android device and forward a TCP connection through the USB cable via adb forward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Robert. The problem with your answer, it's the final user of the two app, don't have the possibility to install adb, on company computer. I try to pass via MTP java librairy(jMTP, jusbpmp) for read and write data from device to computer, but i have a problem, see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645275/desktop-java-app-copy-and-transfer-android-data-via-usb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I success to transfer android data to desktop java app via simple USB cable with [jMTP library](https://code.google.com/p/jmtp/).

You can see how in my anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645275/desktop-java-app-copy-and-transfer-android-data-via-usb/29768435#29768435)

Hope it help.

Comment: PortableDeviceToHostImpl32  is not found in this library