# Desktop java app copy and transfer android data via USB

Tags: java, android, usb, mtp, wpd

I have a desktop java app, and also an android app. Two app work together.

The user in desktop app have a button to launch the transfer between device data app to computer app and vice versa.

So I need to transfer data with a simple USB cable, and without internet connection/WiFi/Bluetooth/adb.

I found two Java MTP library that works on Windows to resolve my problem, and the USB Host/accesory fonctionnality of android:

- **jMTP** successfully recognizes my Android devices, folder, and other things

  I have success to transfer a file in computer ---> device, but i have an error when i try to transfer a file in device ---> computer

  I put my code after the explaination.
- **jusbpmp** but i don't have the possibility to transfer device ---> computer.
- **USB Host/accesory** not usefull because transfer are launch from desktop app, and when i read on the android developper guide website, it seems to be not correspond from what i need, or maybe if the user start transfer from the device.

I try from 1 week to success in this task but it seems i need help.

Java + jMTP code

```
private static void jMTPeMethode() 
        {
            PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
            PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
            // Connect to USB tablet
            device.open();

            System.out.println(device.getModel());

            System.out.println("---------------");

            // Iterate over deviceObjects
            for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) 
            {
                // If the object is a storage object
                if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) 
                {
                    PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

                    for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) 
                    {
                        if(o2.getOriginalFileName().equalsIgnoreCase("Test"))
                        {

                            //Device to computer not working
                            PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 copy = new PortableDeviceToHostImpl32();
                            try 
                            {
                                copy.copyFromPortableDeviceToHost(o2.getID(), "C:\\TransferTest", device);
                            } catch (COMException ex) 
                            {

                            }

    //                      //Host to Device working
    //                      BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
    //                      File file = new File("c:/GettingJMTP.pdf");
    //                      try {
    //                          storage.addAudioObject(file, "jj", "jj", bigInteger1);
    //                      } catch (Exception e) {
    //                          //System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
    //                      }
                        }
                        System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                    }
                }
            }

            manager.getDevices()[0].close();
        }
```

This is the result of the code and the error

```
`

    Nexus 9
    ---------------
    Music
    Podcasts
    Ringtones
    Alarms
    Notifications
    Pictures
    Movies
    Download
    DCIM
    Android
    ! Failed to get IStream (representing object data on the device) from IPortableDeviceResources, hr = 0x80070057
    test
    ReleveData

`
```

I read in internet 0x80070057 is a generic windows exception .

**Edit:**

[Windows site say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the hr error
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 0x80070057 :
The parameter supplied by the application is not valid.

But i don't see witch parameter is not valid

---

Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/jmtp/issues/attachmentText?id=3&aid=30007000&name=PortableDeviceToHost.cpp&token=ABZ6GAcaCcpVr5uFP-1zQnP_D45eX6e5Qw%3A1428068801202) of C class of the library use for transfer data device to computer, you can see my error line 230.

And this is the jMTP library i use.

Can you help me, or purpose an other way to do what i need(Usb4Java, libUSB) ? I shall be really grateful.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem.

The problem come from `o2.getID()` parameter give to the methode `copy.copyFromPortableDeviceToHost`.

Because `o2` representing the folder, and not the file in the folder, so it's not possible to send folder, for success i need to send file in folder.

So i cast my `PortableDeviceObject` o2 to an `PortableDeviceFolderObject`, so that get a list of child Object with `targetFolder.getChildObjects()` in the `PortableDeviceFolderObject` representing files' and then i can iterate on any child objet from the folder.

And for each file i call the methode `copy.copyFromPortableDeviceToHost`, with the right id.

Here is the correction code, copy/transfer file from computer to device and device to computer.

I hope it's help.

```
public class USBTransfertMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        jMTPeMethode();
    }

    private static void jMTPeMethode() 
    {
        PortableDeviceFolderObject targetFolder = null;
        PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
        PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
        // Connect to USB tablet
        device.open();
        System.out.println(device.getModel());

        System.out.println("---------------");

        // Iterate over deviceObjects
        for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) 
        {
            // If the object is a storage object
            if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) 
            {
                PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

                for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) 
                {
                    if(o2.getOriginalFileName().equalsIgnoreCase("testFolder"))
                    {
                        targetFolder = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o2;
                    }

                    System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                }

                copyFileFromComputerToDeviceFolder(targetFolder);
                PortableDeviceObject[] folderFiles = targetFolder.getChildObjects();
                for (PortableDeviceObject pDO : folderFiles) {
                    copyFileFromDeviceToComputerFolder(pDO, device);
                }

            }
        }

        manager.getDevices()[0].close();
    }

    private static void copyFileFromDeviceToComputerFolder(PortableDeviceObject pDO, PortableDevice device)
    {
        PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 copy = new PortableDeviceToHostImpl32();
        try {
            copy.copyFromPortableDeviceToHost(pDO.getID(), "C:\\TransferTest", device);
        } catch (COMException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void copyFileFromComputerToDeviceFolder(PortableDeviceFolderObject targetFolder) 
    {
        BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
        File file = new File("C:\\GettingJMTP.pdf");
        try {
            targetFolder.addAudioObject(file, "jj", "jj", bigInteger1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 is not found in current library