# ADB send file from device to PC

Tags: java, android, adb

I am a fourth year student at computer science and I started a project for my senior thesis.
The project consists of an Android application which takes a pictures using phone's camera and stores it in phone memory, after that the app should send the picture using ADB (or something else) to a PC. The next picture should be also sent and so on... I need to do this from Android Studio using code (the picture should be sent automatically after it is taken).

My problem is that I can't find any way to do this using specific code instructions.

Is this even possible such an app?
How can I send a .jpg file from phone's memory for example?

Comment: So an app that takes pictures and sends them to a pc? Why should this *not* be possible?

Comment: well , this part that i've described , is just the starting point of the app

Comment: I am quite new in Android Studio programming

Comment: ok, so what's your *actual* question?

Comment: "My problem is that i can't find any way to do this using specific code instructions.

Is this even possible such an app? How can I send a .jpg file from phone's memory for example?"

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645275/desktop-java-app-copy-and-transfer-android-data-via-usb) for some idea.

Comment: Thank you for help Federico!